# Where is the meteor.js file?

Tags: meteor, easyrtc

EasyRTC inside Meteor error

I am trying to run a second EasyRTC server and access this server inside Meteor. This is the tutorial I am working from:

https://easyrtc.com/docs/easyrtc_with_other_servers.php

The program works fine within a basic express server, so my problem must have something to do with Meteor. These are my browser console errors:

```
Exception in defer callback: bad video element id undefined  meteor.js:994:11
Exception from Tracker recompute function:  meteor.js:992:11
undefined  meteor.js:994:11
```

So the first question is, where is the meteor.js file, so I can at least see where my error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at meteor.js probably won't help you much.

Search your code for `bad video element id`, or search the library you are using.

It is likely that you are not passing through a bad id, or an undefined object to a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab in the dark and it worked. I changed my video.js file from:

```
Template.video.onCreated(function() {
  connect();
});
```

to:

```
Template.video.onRendered(function() {
  connect();
});
```

I guess it was trying to find the video element id before the page loaded, which I guess you can’t do. I still have problems. I now get the error message:

```
Invalid URI. Load of Media resources failed.
```

But I get a local video on the screen, so that’s progress.
Thanks.